# Facebook Messenger Webhook weird subscription error

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-webhooks

I'm trying to re-subscribe an app to facebook (through graph-api post/me/subscribed-apps). The subscription worked the first time and received `{success: true}`, however now I'm receiving the following error:

```
{"error":
{"message":"(#2) Messaging Subscription Failed for app: <appID>. 
Another Subscription Update is in Progress 2",
"type":"OAuthException",
"is_transient":true,
"code":2,
}}
```

I tried replacing the token but I'm still getting this.
Has anyone encountered this before? Tried looking for reference but with no luck.

Thanks in advance!